# Can TextEdit save as plain text?

Tags: encoding, textedit, macos

When I try to save a new file in TextEdit, I always get a popup saying I can't save with ".txt" at the end of the file name.

I want to save a plaintext file, but TextEdit insists on saving as .rtf instead. It also lists .doc, .odt, .html, and some others.

**How can I save a TextEdit document as plain text?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The format menu has a toggle to switch things for you.

Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> will toggle the document to plain text mode.
[image: Screen Capture showing the Make Plain Text menu item for Text Edit]

You can also set the default format in the preference pane for the app.

[image: Mojave dark mode screen capture of Text Edit preferences showing the RTF / TXT radio button preferences]

Comment: Great Answer!
This is absolutely absurb, that Apple do not provide .txt as a file type option out of the box.
To have to change preferences to enable.txt is crazy.
especially for an application called "TextEdit"

Comment: Do note that the best part of this answer is the second picture showing how to turn on .txt in preferences.

The first part of this answer is a workaround.
And it would be good to describe: Firstly save as rtf, then convert to txt, and then paste in your plain text. then save again, now you will have 2 files, and can delete the rtf.

Comment: @TheArchitecta: I just created a new doc, pasted in some text, clicked "Make Plain Text" in the Format menu (as shown in the first image in the answer), then went to save the file – and it defaulted to saving that file as `.txt`. You don't actually need to save the file as `.rtf` in the first place – though if you had already saved it as `.rtf`, then presumably it would indeed create a new file when you saved the plaintext version as `.txt`. (The second part of the answer is just explaining how to change the default format for new files.)